# How can I add a function extension for Fragment class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

At present, I use Code B to display a message in a Fragment class, it works well.

I hope to use Code A to do it, so I write Code C, but Code C is wrong, how can I fix Code C ? Thanks!

**Code A**

```
import org.jetbrains.anko.*
class UIFragmentCamera : Fragment() {
   private fun updateCameraUi() {
       toast("Hello")
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
import org.jetbrains.anko.*
class UIFragmentCamera : Fragment() {
   private fun updateCameraUi() {
        requireContext().toast("Hello")
    }
}
```

**Code C**

```
fun Fragment.toast(info:String) {
    requireActivity().toast(info)
}
```

Comment: Make sure your imported `Fragment` class are matching (you can either have `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` or `android.app.Fragment`)

Comment: I have added the answer if it is not working. please post the toast function definition which will help us to figure out the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you imported `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` or `android.app.Fragment` in the extension function defined file

`requireActivity` returns `FragmentActivity` whereas `requireContext` returns `Context`. I believe your `toast` is another extension function which display message based on the type `Context`

**Code C**

```
fun Context.toast(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

fun Fragment.toast(info: String) {
    requireContext().toast(info)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option - 1:** If you want to create extension function of `Fragment` class you have to do it in this way

```
fun Fragment.toast(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

And from inside fragment you can call this like below:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    //Here it is 
    toast("Hello")

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
}
```

**Option - 2:**  You can create extension function for `Context` class like this

```
fun Context.toast(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Then you can call this from `Fragment` like below:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    //Here it is, both are valid
    requireActivity().toast("Hello")
    requireContext().toast("World")

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
}
```

You can also call this from `Activity` like below:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    toast("Hello World")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment


fun Fragment.toast(message :String ){
    Toast.makeText(requireContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```